# Stylize or format text in R Shiny Server

Tags: html, r, shiny, shiny-server

I have an app running on shiny server and I would like to format smalls parts of text without needing to manage the css/html for the entirety of the page.

#### Simple example:

In the `ui.r`, I have some lines of help text that I would like to stylize.

```
sidebarPanel(
 ...
 , helpText("<I>Can</I> <em>this</em> <strong>happen</strong>?")
 )
```

Which gives:

```
# Current Output: 
<I>Can</I> <em>this</em> <strong>happen</strong>?
```

> #desired Output:
>   *Can* *this* **happen**?

The text is (understandably) rendered as a literal string.
Is there a function or command to force the HTML to be parsed?

Comment: You maybe able to use the `HTML` function to prevent the HTML being escaped.

Comment: @jdharrison, that's it, thanks!  Post it as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use this:

```
sidebarPanel(
 ...
 , HTML("<I>Can</I> <em>this</em> <strong>happen</strong>?")
 )
```

As an aside, you can even use renderText on the server side to build a full HTML output string, which can change, depending on your inputs. I often use this to post automated commentary (e.g. "The latest data release is y.... this is an increase of y, relative to the previous release...").

Comment: In regards to the aside, if I use `renderText` in the server to build an html string, like `<strong>my reactive heading</strong>my reactive text` then how do I output that on the UI side?  I tried `HTML(textOutput("theOutput"))` and that didn't work.  Thanks!